# Typescript cannot find name 'doPostBack'

Tags: asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm migrating some existing JavaScript in an ASP.NET web application to Typescript and came across the following line in the JavaScript:

`__doPostBack('ccm$ctl00$_ColumnDesigner', 'radW');`

Typescript produces the error: *Cannot find name 'doPostBack'.* I'm stuck on how to resolve this. Anybody know how?

The JavaScript is located in a .js file and is part of a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl` object. The script is registered using the `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Control, Type, resourceName)` method.

Comment: you will have to give us more info. where is that method coming from? a library, is some of your code making a global function? how is the project set up?

Comment: look at that bit of code, I guess you have a global function that is defined in a different file, and typescript knows nothing of it.

Comment: __doPostBack is ASP.NET's very own JavaScript function, and is the function that ASP.NET itself uses to post back to the server. It is very commonly used and I find it very strange that Microsoft's TypeScript has no idea what it is. Why haven't they provided type information of ASP.NET's JavaScript functions?

Comment: it doesn't look like there's a definition file made for ASP.NET functions. The best solution is the one proposed by @basarat

Comment: You are correct. I've accepted @basarat's proposal but also added an answer of my own showing the line I added. Hopefully this will help others in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> __doPostBack('ccm$ctl00$_ColumnDesigner', 'radW');
>   Typescript produces the error: Cannot find name 'doPostBack'

Just declare it in a file `globals.d.ts`:

```
declare var __doPostBack:any;
```

## More

Check the quick migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: Followed your advice and created a globals.d.ts file but added the following line instead: `declare function __doPostBack(eventTarget: string, eventArguments: any)`.